# I can't use findViewById

Tags: android, android-fragments

Why can't I use `findViewById` in this file?

Regfragment :

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class RegFragment extends Fragment {

EditText text1,text2,text3;
Button btn1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);

    return rootView;


}
}
```

and then I tried to make like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class RegFragment extends Fragment {

EditText text1,text2,text3;
Button btn1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);

    return rootView;

    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);   -----> ERROR....
}
}
```

I got error
Is it because I use Fragments ?

Comment: probably getting `unreachable statement` because you are initializing  textview after return statement so use `text1 = (EditText)rootView. findViewById(R.id.text1)` before return statement

Comment: Check out my answer and change your code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much sir....why i didn't try like that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can not use it in fragment because it's method of activity

try following

in onActivityCreated()

`text1 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.text1);`

or in onCreateView()

`text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);`

Comment: `text1 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text1);` is wrong allthough i din't downvote. should use `getView()`

Comment: not right. wrong. you can't use the first in onActivityCreated

Comment: we can use and I am using in app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43867/discussion-between-ketan-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 3):

you have used inflater

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);
```

so use

```
text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1); 
text2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2); 
text3 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it before return statement like this way

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);
   text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    return rootView;
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

To access the view in the fragment you need to access it through your `View` class which contains your layout.

You need to change your code as below :

```
public class RegFragment extends Fragment {

EditText text1,text2,text3;
Button btn1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);
    text1 = (EditText)rootView .findViewById(R.id.text1); 
    //Same way initialize other views also. 
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just a simple way. you already inflated the layout. just inherit from that. find the code below**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);
text1 = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1); 

return rootView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used a separate View to inflate your layout, you are required to use that view to access all text views/image views/edit text present in that layout.

So to correct your code, you would need to tweak your code like shown below

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_layout, container, false);
text1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
return rootView;
```